# rails server not starting with cucumber/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm running test's in a new environment that we call as "stub". Using capybara with cucumber-rails. The rails server is not starting, by default. "config.run_server" is set to true.  I tried running in "test" environment too, but the server is not starting. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: same issue posted in capybara page, again redirected here https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1202

Answer (score 1):

I'm using cucumber-rails. I have to add the following lines in Cucumber environment file, "feature/support/env.rb"

```
require File.expand_path('../../../config/environment', FILE)
require ("rspec/rails")
```

Only then capybara, gets hold of the application.